# Authorizing access to specific resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to build a REST API using AWS API Gateway that calls into a bunch of Lambda functions.

I have now set up API Gateway to use a Cognito user pool as the authorizer, but all that's really doing is authenticating the user since I've attached the user pool to all the endpoints. I wasn't able to figure out how to specifically allow certain methods on certain endpoints.

For example, if my user is `123` and belongs to group `ABC`, I would only like them to be able to `GET /users?group=ABC` or `PATCH /users/123`.

Is it possible to achieve this level of control or do I need to implement those checks in the Lambda function that API Gateway calls?

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a similar setup and I faced the exact same issue. My team could not find a solution to this, so we contacted an AWS solutions architect. Here is a summary of their approach to this problem.

Unfortunately there are no default built-in solutions to this specific problem. However you can use some alternative solutions.

1. It is possible to trigger Lambda functions during Cognito user pool workflows. You may use an extra Lambda function to authorize users by checking their user-group relationships.
   [Customizing User Pool Workflows with Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html)
2. You can use API Gateway Lambda authorizer. In this case you will have to give up the Cognito integration and apply your custom authorization logic inside the authorizer Lambda.
   [Use API Gateway Lambda authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html)
3. You can implement the authorization logic inside the lambda functions with an extra query by checking the user-group relationship. You can check the identity of the requesting (Cognito) user through `requestContext.authorizer.claims.*` in the Lambda event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse yes u can do it. this will help you.. if u get stuck.. ping me back

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-scopes-api-gateway/

Comment: I guess this is me being a newbie on this, but I'm still unclear about 2 things: how do you determine which users are authorized for which scopes? within an endpoint/method, which is tied to a scope, is there a distinction between authorizing depending on path/query params? Also I'm using custom auth, I assume that doesn't matter?

Comment: Any update on @wizplum 's comment? I am having the exact same issue and could not figure out a way to limit the access of cognito users based on path/query parameters.

Comment: I also haven't figured this out yet